# record for last two month and their difference in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i need variance for last two month and i am using below query

```
with Positions as
(
select  
    COUNT(DISTINCT A_SALE||B_SALE) As SALES, 
    TO_CHAR(DATE,'YYYY-MON') As Period
from ORDERS
where DATE between date '2020-02-01' and date '2020-02-29'
group by TO_CHAR(DATE,'YYYY-MON') 

union all

select  
    COUNT(DISTINCT A_SALE||B_SALE) As SALES, 
    TO_CHAR(DATE,'YYYY-MON') As Period
from ORDERS
where DATE between date '2020-03-01' and date '2020-03-31'
group by TO_CHAR(DATE,'YYYY-MON') 

)
select  
    SALES,
    period,
    case when to_char(round((SALES-lag(SALES,1, SALES) over (order by period desc))/ SALES*100,2), 'FM999999990D9999') <0 
         then to_char(round(abs( SALES-lag(SALES,1, SALES) over (order by period desc))/ SALES*100,2),'FM999999990D9999')||'%'||'  (Increase) '
         when to_char(round((SALES-lag(SALES,1,SALES) over (order by period  desc))/SALES*100,2),'FM999999990D9999')>0 
         then to_char(round(abs(SALES-lag(SALES,1, SALES) over (order by period desc ))/SALES*100,2),'FM999999990D9999')||'%'||'  (Decrease) '
    END as variances
from Positions  
order by Period;
```

i am getting output like this

```
SALES    |     Period       |     variances
---------|------------------|--------------------
100      |  2020-FEB        |     100%(Increase)
200      |  2020-MAR        |       NULL
```

i want record something like that where variance in front of march instead of feb as we are looking variance for the latest month

```
SALES    |     Period       |     variances
---------|------------------|--------------------
200      |  2020-MAR        |     100%(Increase)
100      |  2020-FEB        |       NULL
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle?!?

Comment: (sqldeveloper)Oracle.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not analyze the query in too much detail but you have one obvious flaw.
You change your period from a date to char.
That means when you apply your window functions your ordering will not work as expected.

a date ordered desc will look like (based on chronological ordering)

```
MAR - 2020
FEB - 2020
JAN - 2020
```

Text ordered desc will look like (based on alphabetical ordering)

```
MAR - 2020
JAN - 2020
FEB - 2020
```

That being said, you are comparing a 'good' case (FEB + MAR) where both the text ordering and date ordering will work the same way.

The implied ordering is ASCENDING. So at the end when you do

```
order by Period;
```

it will display February first and then March. If you do

```
order by Period DESC;
```

you will get March displayed first.

Comment: hey thanks..
actually i want records where i can find variance between two months for latest months,          SALES | Period | variances

200 | 2020-MAR | 100%(Increase) 100 | 2020-FEB | NULL now, i am getting variance in front of feb